# Wire connection with repetitor

Tags: wireless-networking, mac, wireless-access-point, wired-networking

At home I have only 3 ethernet points from fiber, one is using a router do give wireless access. the other 2 are not been used. 
As the wireless signal is week in many points of the house, I could install some repeters, but the signal is not good, I mean the internet speed downgrade a lot.
My questions: 
1-can I install normal wireless routers in the other 2 points? 
2- Will it be better than repeaters? 
3- Can I use old modems? not too old of course.

4- How should I install, as a new or same name network?

Need some help I am completely new in the matter :(.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing more wireless routers will probably make things worse. Those things will be trying to find frequencies they can use and shouting over the top of one another and generally adding noise.

Wireless repeaters are designed for the job you want.

You might be able to [reconfigure a router as a wireless repeater](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-extend-your-wi-fi-network-with-an-old-router-915783308) - but this may not be easy.

Comment: Tks RedGrittyBrick, the installation of the wired is the three points are connected to the fiber so if I connect the Ethernet I get internet connection with same speed 25mb. But everyone wants wireless. I will try repeaters, but repeaters uses only wireless or they can repeat signal from Ethernet cable?